# Source code available that shows how to load a .ani file?

Tags: .net, windows, riff

Is there a .NET library or source code available somewhere that would allow me to get the internals of a .ani file?  Most loaders just allow me to pass a cursor object to other interfaces but I need to query a cursor object about the icons, timings, etc.

(If I have to, I can write my own reader based on this spec: http://www.gdgsoft.com/anituner/help/aniformat.htm.)